# Spring AMQP Dynamically create RabbitTemplate and SimpleMessageListenerContainer, error RabbitTemplate is not configured as MessageListener

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to implement a gateway in Spring Boot, having REST endpoints and inserting the messages in a RabbitMQ broker. I need to handle the errors, so I configured a replyAddress with a DLQ, and a SimpleMessageListenerContainer with my RabbitTemplate to mark it as "listener" and be able to consume the replyQueue.

It works fine with "hard coded" beans :

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setReceiveTimeout(0);
    template.setReplyTimeout(10000);
    template.setExchange("inputExchange");
    template.setRoutingKey("routing.1");
    template.setReplyAddress("replyQueue1");

    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    classMapper.setDefaultType(Event.class);
    messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);

    return template;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("replyQueue1");
    container.setMessageListener(rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory));
    return container;
}
```

But the goal of this Gateway is to be entirely configurable, so not to code every route to a Rabbit exchange/queue.

For example, I have this configuration in a yaml :

```
routes:
  service1:
    exchange: inputExchange
    queue: inputQueue1
    routing: routing.1
    replyQueue: replyQueue1
    dlExchange: reply.dlx1
    dlQueue: dlx.queue1.reply
    receiveTimeout: 0
    replyTimeout: 10000
    preProcessors: package.processor.LowercaseProcessor
    postProcessors: package.processor.UppercaseProcessor
  service2:
    exchange: inputExchange
    queue: inputQueue2
    routing: routing.2
```

So I need to dynamically create my RabbitTemplate and SimpleMessageListenerContainer to configure for each service the replyQueue, the DLQ, ...

I tried with this code :

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitTemplatesConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

    @Autowired
    private GatewayProperties properties;
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void configure() {
        Assert.state(beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableBeanFactory, "wrong bean factory type");
        ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;

        Map<String, ServiceProperties> routes = properties.getRoutes();
        if (routes != null) {
            for (String service : routes.keySet()) {
                ServiceProperties props = routes.get(service);
                createTemplate(configurableBeanFactory, service, props);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTemplate(ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory, String service, ServiceProperties props) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setExchange(props.getExchange());
        template.setRoutingKey(props.getRouting());
        template.setReplyAddress(props.getReplyQueue());

        template.setReceiveTimeout(props.getReceiveTimeout());
        template.setReplyTimeout(props.getReplyTimeout());

        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        classMapper.setDefaultType(Event.class);
        messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);

        configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(service + "Template", template);

        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(props.getReplyQueue())) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(props.getReplyQueue());
            container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(template));
            configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(service + "ListenerContainer", container);
            container.afterPropertiesSet(); //added this but not working either
            container.start(); //added this but not working either
        }
    }
}
```

but when I receive the response on the replyQueue, I have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RabbitTemplate is not configured as MessageListener - cannot use a 'replyAddress': replyQueue1
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceiveWithFixed(RabbitTemplate.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1251)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveRaw(RabbitTemplate.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1156)
```

So the SimpleMessageListenerContainer doesn't seem to be properly instantiated / configured.

Do you know what is the problem ?

My code sending and receiving :

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
@Autowired
private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;
@Autowired
private GatewayProperties properties;

@PostMapping("/{service}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> call(@PathVariable("service") String service, @RequestBody Event body) {
    ServiceProperties serviceProperties = properties.getRoutes().get(service);

    Queue queue = QueueBuilder.durable(serviceProperties.getQueue()).build();
    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange(serviceProperties.getExchange());
    rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(serviceProperties.getRouting()));

    Queue replyQueue = null;
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(serviceProperties.getReplyQueue())) {
        replyQueue = QueueBuilder.durable(serviceProperties.getReplyQueue()).withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", serviceProperties.getDlExchange()).build();
        rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(replyQueue);
        Queue dlQueue = QueueBuilder.durable(serviceProperties.getDlQueue()).build();
        rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(dlQueue);
        TopicExchange dlqExchange = new TopicExchange(serviceProperties.getDlExchange());
        rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(dlqExchange);
        rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(dlQueue).to(dlqExchange).with(serviceProperties.getReplyQueue()));
    }

    RabbitTemplate template = (RabbitTemplate) context.getBean(service + "Template");

    Event outputMessage = (Event) template.convertSendAndReceive(serviceProperties.getExchange(), serviceProperties.getRouting(), body, new CorrelationData(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you are using a reply queue; RabbitMQ now provides a direct reply-to mechanism which removes most of the reasons for using a fixed reply queue (one exception is if you want an HA reply queue).

That said, the problem is you are wrapping the template in a `MessageListenerAdapter` - this is not necessary (and won't work anyway) - the template implements `MessageListener`.

Comment: Wahou it works ! Thanks for your quick help. One day I was on it :/ I do this because I want a dead letter queue in case of timeout of the response for example. Do you think that there is a better implementation for handling the possible errors ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; handling a timeout is the same, regardless of how the `replyTo` is set up (listener container with fixed queue, temporary queue, or direct reply-to).

Comment: If I use the default direct-reply-to queue (amq.rabbitmq.reply-to), I don't have a DLQ so the message, consumed and in error (for any reason), is set back to the queue and consumed indefinitly (imagine that the third party app where the message should go is disconnected). So I needed a DLQ to store these message not processable and saw this implementation of setting it in the replyQueue argument. Is there a better error management ?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want a DLQ on the reply queue so that late replies are DLQ'd. Got it.